flutter web - firestore hangs on query snapshot stream randomly
I'm trying to fetch data using firestore stream on flutter application, however, this query randomly hangs and never come back
Here is how I'm trying to read:
Stream<List<Package>> getPackages(
  DateTime? fromDate,
  DateTime? endDate,
  List<String>? driversIDs,
  List<String>? storesIDs,
  List<PackageStatus>? packageStatuses,
  int limit,
  ) async* {

  Query<Object?> query = packagesRef;
  List<Filter> filters = [];
  if (fromDate != null) {
    filters.add(Filter('creationDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: fromDate));
  }
  if (endDate != null) {
    filters.add(Filter('creationDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDate));
  }
  if (packageStatuses != null &&
      packageStatuses.isNotEmpty &&
      !setEquals(packageStatuses.toSet(), PackagesStatus.values.toSet())) {
    Filter? packagesFilter = buildWhereInQuery(
        'currentStatus', packageStatuses.map((r) => r.toString()).toList());
    if (packagesFilter != null) {
      filters.add(packagesFilter);
    }
  }

  bool filterDrivers = false;
  if (driversIDs != null && driversIDs.isNotEmpty) {
    if (driversIDs.length < kMaxServerWhereInQuerySize) {
      filterDrivers = false;
      Filter? driversFilter = buildWhereInQuery('driverID', driversIDs);
      if (driversFilter != null) {
        filters.add(driversFilter);
      }
    } else {
      filterDrivers = true;
    }
  }
  bool filterStores = false;
  if (storesIDs != null && storesIDs.isNotEmpty) {
    if (storesIDs.length < kMaxServerWhereInQuerySize) {
      filterStores = false;
      Filter? storesFilter = buildWhereInQuery('storeID', storesIDs);
      if (storesFilter != null) {
        filters.add(storesFilter);
      }
    } else {
      filterStores = true;
    }
  }
  Filter? andFilter = combineAndFilters(filters);
  if (andFilter != null) {
    query = query.where(andFilter);
  }
  query = query.orderBy('creationDate', descending: true);
  if (limit > 0) {
    query = query.limit(limit);
  }

  Function? filterFunction;
  if (filterStores || filterDrivers) {
    filterFunction = (Package package) {
      return (!filterStores || storesIDs!.contains(package.storeID)) &&
          (!filterDrivers || driversIDs!.contains(package.driverID));
    };
  }

  await for (QuerySnapshot e in query.snapshots()) {
    print('here ---');
    List<Package> packagesList = [];
    for (var doc in e.docs) {
      var data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      Package package = Package.fromDocument(data);
      if (filterFunction != null) {
        if (!filterFunction(package)) {
          continue;
        }
      }
      packagesList.add(package);
    }
    print('done');
    yield packagesList;
}

The query sometimes work and sometimes does not, the print('here ---') sometime got printed and other does not at all. hence, the for(...) does not finish and print('done') is not printed no matter how much I wait.
where the helpers functions are building the query using the Filter object as following (query has 1 attribute, so pasting relevant part):
Filter? buildWhereInQuery(String attributeName, List<String> values) {
if (values.isEmpty) {
  return null;
}
if (values.length == 1) {
  return Filter(attributeName, isEqualTo: values[0]);
}
...
}

and,
Filter? combineAndFilters(List<Filter> filters) {
if (filters.isEmpty) {
  return null;
}
if (filters.length == 1) {
  return filters[0];
}
if (filters.length > 10) {
  throw Exception('Fix and filter combination, exceeded number');
}

return Filter.and(
  filters[0],
  filters[1],
  ...
);

}
Note: I'm aware of the query "and" limitations of Firebase, but in my case, I'm not passing more than 2 items to filter upon, so this limitation is not relevant in my case.
I'm using the latest versions of flutter and firebase packages of all (firebase core and cloud firestore).

Your code seems to be missing the actual Firestore query.  What you have now looks like it's just iterating query results.  Where is query defined?  Please edit the question to show all of the code necessary to reproduce the unexpected results.

Also keep in mind that your for loop will print nothing at all if there is nothing to iterate in query.snapshots().  We can't see the data that you're working with, so we don't know what this loop is going to do.

Thanks for your reply, edited according per your request

Please also edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your Firebase Console.

I will try to create a sample database and add it here, I'm use firestore tho, with documents
